# Jquery / Daterangepicker problem , Allow to change date only by "Apply Button"

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, daterangepicker

Im Using Jquery daterangepicker,

I want to cancel the option to set dates if the user not click on the apply button .

Right now, When the user click outside of the box of daterangepicker,  the dates is set (I dont want it to happend).

Why I want to do it?
Becuse I set an event that when click applybtn , The startDate and endDate will sent to my hidden inputs then It will be easier to work on it with the backend.

I also tried to use AutoApply.. but the problem is that I cannot find any event that detect this auto apply.

I need to detect the event because I want to immidietly sent the data to my hidden inputs.

Thank you In advance for help .

[image: Date range picker]

Answer (score 0):

Allright, so you got few options hare, both of them will come with a little bit of a hustle.

**The first one:**

*You could attach datepicker to an invisible input, furthermore, you can attach an extra event on apply button (Not sure if datePicker has event on clikc), but you could easily attach it on datepicker summon, and then you could update the visible input, leaving the invisible one constantly changing.*

**Second one is:**

*You could look around for alternative datepickers, or create your own, you could just download simplified datepicker that doesnt hold eventholders.*

**The third option:**

*You could overwrite excisting event, which wouldnt be advisible, but I am going to throw it out there ether way.*

My personal opinion, if I would need to something like that, I would create invisible input and attach an event on apply button. The apply button always has the same class, make sure to summon date picker in the same wrapper and then just simply find it by `$('div.someDateDiv>datepicker>.button'); //Not an actual code.`

Since datepicker is already in build package, they built it as they imagined comfortable and gonna be most used like, so tweaking it might come with a bit of a hustle.

Good luck!

Comment: Hello , Thank you very much for a clear and privatized answer, What I found that .. problem was that I cannot find any event that detect Auto set of daterangepicker. Why apply button is not good for me? becuse the daterangepicker will set by defult by choosing the endDate. 
I wanted to find this event to be able to set the startDate + endDate in hidden inputs that I prepared in advance right after the datepicker is set. 
While I didnt find any of that event that work , even after looking the documentations, I decide to loop thru all datepickers and reset it right before submiting form.

Comment: Right, that makes sense, I think you need a simplyer lib that only gives you style and basic javascript things. Since you are kind of attaching events on your own. But it makes sense, somehow canceling the fired event and doing it on your own is also viable.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent users from manually editing the dates in the DateRangePicker input fields, you can use the readonly attribute or disable text input using JavaScript. Here's how you can achieve this:

Using readonly attribute:

html

```
<input type="text" class="dateRangePicker" readonly>
```

Using JavaScript to disable text input:
Using JavaScript to disable text input:

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Disable text input for elements with class 'dateRangePicker'
        $('.dateRangePicker').on('keydown', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
    </script>
```